# How do you make the banner and CSS menu a specific color, and the rest a different color?

Tags: html, css, banner

So, I don't know how to explain this really well. My website has a banner (it's a picture) at the top and then a menu underneath the banner, and I want the menu and above to have a dark gray background, with the rest a really light grey background. How would I do this?

This is what my website layout currently looks like (excuse the horrible art): [image]

This is what I want the website to look like: (notice the background colors)
[image]

Comment: You should add some code with the basic layout so we can help you better :) try jsfiddle.com

Comment: Just use the basic [`background-color`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-color.asp) css attribute.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div style='background:#123'>
      your banner
    </div>
    <div style='background:#567'>
      your text
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

or

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel=stylesheet type="text/css" href="my.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class='banner'>
      your banner
    </div>
    <div class='main'>
      your text
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and in my.css

```
.banner {background:#123}
.main {background:#456}
```